# Probability: Drawing 3 balls with consecutive numbers

Tags: probability

there are 40 balls in a basket in 4 colors: Black(B), White(W), Red(R), Green(G) each color which has number 1 to 10 balls.
So we have:

- B1 to B10
- W1 to W10
- R1 to R10
- G1 to G10

Question1:
What is the probability of drawing 3 balls with consecutive numbers of 4,5,6 OR 5,6,7 OR 6,7,8 OR 7,8,9?

Question2:
Question one with one more condition: No more than one ball is red. (For example W6,B7,G8 and B4,B5,R6 are acceptable but R5,W6,R7 is not.)

I am so confused because I end up with a Negative probability.

Thank you

Comment: Is R6, B5, and R7 acceptable? Must you draw one of the sequences *in order*?

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable. 9G,7B,8W is another acceptable example.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

Number of possible drawings: $\binom{40}3$.
Number of valid drawings: there are $4$ possibilities for the numbers, and the balls can be coloured in $4^3$ ways.
Probability:
$$\frac{\binom{40}3}{4\cdot4^3}$$

**Q2**

Since the combinations of colours $RRR$ and $RR?$ (in any order) are forbidden, the number of valid combinations of colours are $4^3-1-3\cdot 3$. (The product $3\cdot 3$ is three possible colours for the non red ball and three possible positions in the sequence). 
Probability:
$$\frac{\binom{40}3}{4\cdot(4^3-10)}$$

Comment: nice, much simpler than what I did (if mine is even right, heh), your fractions are upside down tho

Comment: In your answer to Q1 I actually can't understand why "There are 4 possibilities for the numbers".

Comment: @Yavar its the list you gave, there are 4 three number runs

Comment: @btcgurl so how do we take into account the overlap of two three number runs?